# Como usar vários comandos SQL (no caso delete no ORACLE) em uma linha só no C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ado.net

Fiz um comando por causa de foreign keys, só pra tapar buraco, mas não está funcionando por um erro de caractere inválido, acredito que seja o `";"`.

Sei que estou fazendo isso da maneira mais errada possível, então aceito sugestões de um código mais adequado. A principio só preciso fazer isso funcionar, pois é só uma demostração da aplicação.

Segue o código:

```cpp
    public string ExcluirIndicador(int codigo)
    {
        try
        {
            comand = connectionFactory.CreateCommand();
            comand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "; DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "; DELETE FROM TB_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "";
            comand.Connection = connection;
            comand.ExecuteReader();

            return "Sucesso";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var erro = e.Message;
            return "Erro";
        }
    }
```

O erro:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character\n
```

Comment: Debuga para saber exatamente o erro, o código está vindo corretamente? Aqui eu executei um command com mais de um delete e funcionou normal.

Comment: O padrão do seu projeto é construir as consultas SQL no C# e apenas executar no bancou ou você pode ter uma procedure no banco que é executada apenas no c#?

Answer (score 6):

Tente por as querys dentro de um Anonymous Blocks `BEGIN..END`

### O que são Anonymous Blocks?

- São declarados numa aplicação no local onde devem ser executados, sendo passados em *run-time* ao *interpretador PL/SQL*, normalmente são construídos dinamicamente e executados apenas uma vez.

#### Exemplo

```sql
BEGIN DELETE FROM; DELETE FROM...; DELETE FROM...; END;
```

```cs
    public string ExcluirIndicador(int codigo)
    {
        try
        {
            comand = connectionFactory.CreateCommand();
            comand.CommandText = "BEGIN DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "; DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "; DELETE FROM TB_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + " END";
            comand.Connection = connection;
            comand.ExecuteReader();

            return "Sucesso";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var erro = e.Message;
            return "Erro";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consegue colocar uma explicação, mesmo que rápida? Simplesmente falar "Faça isso" deixa a resposta meio vaga. Tente explicar porque isso é uma solução, qual o intuito, ou qual o "segredo" de porque isso funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Abaixo uma sugestão de melhoria para seu projeto, guardar as *querys* em uma classe separada para caso necessite reutilizar em outro local, caso precise excluir um `TB_INDICADOR` usando outro parâmetro, você pode utilizar sobrecarga de métodos.

```
public string ExcluirIndicador(int codigo)
{
    try
    {
        comand = connectionFactory.CreateCommand();
        comand.CommandText = "BEGIN "+QueryFactory.Exclui_TB_CR_Indicador(codigo) + 
                             QueryFactory.Exclui_TB_CR_Indicador_Periodo(codigo) + 
                             QueryFactory.Exclui_TB_INDICADOR(codigo) + " END;";

        comand.Connection = connection;
        comand.ExecuteReader();

        return "Sucesso";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var erro = e.Message;
        return "Erro";
    }
}

public static class QueryFactory
{
    public static string Exclui_TB_CR_Indicador(int codigo)
    {
        return "DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " +codigo+ ";  ";
    }

    public static string Exclui_TB_CR_Indicador_Periodo(int codigo)
    {
        return "DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " +codigo +"; ";
    }

    public static string Exclui_TB_INDICADOR (int codigo)
    {
        return "DELETE FROM TB_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " +codigo+"; ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Legal a ideia. Retirei o "()" do QueryFactory, mas ainda assim gerou erro: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended\n

Comment: @JoaoPaulo , editei a resposta, poderia verificar agora por favor? obrigado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas tentativas. Ainda traz erro: "ORA-06550: line 1, column 181:\nPLS-00103: Encountered the symbol \"end-of-file\" when expecting one of the following:\n\n   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>\nThe symbol \";\" was substituted for \"end-of-file\" to continue.\n"

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução mais robusta e completa o que sugiro. Sabendo que tudo tem uma solução rápida, fácil e errada, melhor perder tempo na implementação para ganho de qualidade!

```
#region Controle de Transação
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracle"].ConnectionString))
using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        #region excluindo registro da tabela 1'
                        command.CommandText = Constantes.sql1; //Constantes é uma classe estatica com declarações de variaveis ou constantes estaticas onde centraliza os scripts.
                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_codigo ", OracleDbType.int, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = codigo;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                        #endregion

                        #region excluindo registro da tabela 2'
                        command.CommandText = Constantes.sql2;
                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Numreq", OracleDbType.int, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = codigo;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                        #endregion

                        #region excluindo registro da tabela n'
                        command.CommandText = Constantes.sql3;
                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Numreq", OracleDbType.int, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = codigo;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                        #endregion

                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
                //Nestes casos não devolve o requisitorio então não deve atualizar a situação do mesmo!
                catch (OracleException oe) 
                {
                    var retornoAmigavel = Constantes.Error;
                    switch (oe.ErrorCode)
                    {
                        case 12170:
                            retornoAmigavel = oe.ErrorCode +"-"+ Constantes.SemConexao;
                            break;

                        case 28000:
                            retornoAmigavel = oe.ErrorCode + "-" + Constantes.ContaBloqueada;
                            break;

                        case 1073:
                            retornoAmigavel = oe.ErrorCode + "-" + Constantes.ErroDeConexao;
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            retornoAmigavel = oe.ErrorCode + "-" + Constantes.ChavePrimariaViolada;
                            break;

                        default:
                            retornoAmigavel = Constantes.ErroGenerico + oe.Message;
                            break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(retornoAmigavel, oe);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var EretornoAmigavel = "ERROR REQ.Nº: " + requ.numero;
                    EretornoAmigavel += "\nConstantes.ErroGenerico " + e.Message;
                    Console.WriteLine(EretornoAmigavel);
                }
            }
            #endregion
```

É isso! Espero ter contribuido...

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE*

Porque você não executa commands individuais?

```
public string ExcluirIndicador(int codigo)
{
    try
    {
        comand = connectionFactory.CreateCommand();
        comand.Connection = connection; 

        comand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        comand.CommandText = string.Concat("DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = @codigo;",
                                           "DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO WHERE COD_INDICADOR = @codigo;",
                                           "DELETE FROM TB_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = @codigo;");
        comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", codigo);
        comand.ExecuteReader();

        return "Sucesso";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var erro = e.Message;
        return "Erro";
    }
}
```

## Cuidado ao concatenar parâmetros direto no commandText

Se o código puder ser manipulado pelo cliente, a aplicação fica vulnerável a [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

## Observação

Caso seu comando tiver o `ExecuteScalar()` ou `ExecuteNonQuery()` prefira usar eles.

- `ExecuteReader()` - para mais de 1 registro/coluna
- `ExecuteScalar()` - 1 único registro e coluna
- `ExecuteNonQuery()`- sem retorno, apenas execução

Comment: Muito boa a explicação dos usos, mas não funcionou. Ao debugar quando entra no ExecuteNonQuery() ele muda a tela do visual studio pro navegador e nada acontece. Não consigo dar F10 pra seguir pois ele entende que esta rodando.

Comment: A conexão está aberta?

Comment: Acho que sim, pois quando não está eu consigo debugar e verificar isso. Mas debugando não está acusando erro nenhum, somente fica rodando eternamente o ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: Fiz uma alteração para executar os 3 juntos e passando o parâmetro de forma mais segura, você ja tentou executar com a resposta do Laerte?

Comment: Sua alteração precisa de alguma referencia que não descobri qual é. A resposta do Laerte retornou esse erro: "ORA-06550: line 1, column 176:\nPL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended\nORA-06550: line 1, column 125:\nPL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored\nORA-06550: line 1, column 178:\nPLS-00103: Encountered the symbol \"end-of-file\" when expecting one of the following:\n\n   ;\n"

Comment: Qual o problema da referência? Pode postar o código inspirado na resposta do Laerte que você testou?

Comment: Eu editei o post dele com o código que eu testei.

Comment: O AddWithValue está gerando erro de referencia.

Comment: Experimenta trocar por `comand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@codigo", Value = codigo });`

Answer (score 1):

Tente algo assim:

```
string script = "DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "; DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "; DELETE FROM TB_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "";    
Server server = new Server(connection);
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que para o seu código funcionar basta você substituir o

```
comand.ExecuteReader();
```

pela chamada do

```
comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Pois a execução do seu SQL não terá nenhum retorno.

Answer (score -2):

Use o booleano OU no seu where

```
comand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "; DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "; DELETE FROM TB_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo + "";
```

ficaria simplesmente

```
comand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo1 + " || COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo2 + "|| COD_INDICADOR = " + codigo3 + "";
```

não lembro se o oracle tem um in, em MS Sql ficaria assim:

```
comand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TB_CR_INDICADOR WHERE COD_INDICADOR in (" + codigo1 + "," + codigo2 + "," + codigo3 + ")";
```

Comment: Amigo, são tabelas diferentes. Disjunção não irá funcionar neste caso.

Comment: Desculpe amigo, não li corretamente a pergunta (tem como deletar a minha resposta?) Neste caso a resposta do miaocn Carraro parece ser a correta. OP relatou um problema mas parece ser de formatação. Ao criar uma string multilinhas como essa tenta usar: String x = @"linhas uma sobre a outra sem necessidade de concatenação"